# Add a starting the day date column

Tags: python, datetime

This is really easy but I'm completely lost. I want to add a new column that has the starting day of the week. For example for the first row 2021/30 - is the 30th week of the 2021 and the starting day is a Sunday 23rd of May 2021.

Thanks!

[image: Table code weekly]

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the `install_df.index` as datetime, then you can write a simple function to calculate the start date of the week from that date:

```py
def helper(a):
    'helper function calculate beginning date of week'
    d = -1-a.weekday()
    d = 0 if d==-7 else d
    return (a + timedelta(days=d)).strftime('%Y %m %d %A')

# then you can do:
df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_series().apply(helper).to_list()).sum()
```